# If two matrices pre- and post-multipied by same vector yield same number, then are they the same?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratic-forms

I have two matrices $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ and a vector $\mathbf{u}$, and I know that

$$\mathbf{u'Au}=\mathbf{u'Bu}$$

May I conclude from this that $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{B}$? If not please provide a counterexample.

Comment: What is $e_i' \mathbf A e_j$? where $e_i$ is the vector that is all zeros except the $i^{th}$ element is $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Let $$u=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$$ $$A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}$$ $$B=\begin{bmatrix}2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$
Then $$u'Au=u'Bu=3$$

Comment: Ok, but is it true up to a permutation of columns?

Comment: $C=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0.5 \\ 0.5 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ also satisfies $u'Cu=3$. We can also show that the matrces do not have to be symmetrical, or even have that the same determinant, and the elements of the vector need not be the same: let $v=\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$, $D=\begin{bmatrix}2 & 1 \\ 1 & -1\end{bmatrix}$, and $E=\begin{bmatrix}3 & 1 \\ 0 & -3\end{bmatrix}$, then $v'Dv=v'Ev=11$.